# Search for files using terminal and open with preferred program when clicked?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, terminal, search

I would like to somehow create links to files within the terminal from search results found when searching files. Same way you would click a hyperlink within the terminal, but in this case it would be a file and not an URL. Is this possible?

Below is the command in which I am working with.

```
grep -rnw "$2" -e "$1"
```

... and here is a screenshot when searching my logs for term "filezilla"

[image]

I would like to be able to click on the purple text which are exact file locations, the same way I would open a hyperlink within the terminal.

I tried this command below, but all this does is automatically open every search result found with the preferred program, in this case the program being mousepad.

```
grep -rnw "$2" -e "$1" | xargs mousepad
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent terminal emulators do handle hyperlinking to a limited extent. Provided that it 'knows' which programme to use to open a document then you just need to echo the file name to `stdout` in the terminal window with the correct protocol in front. Since we are dealing with local files then this means changing

```
/path/to/file/this.doc
```

to

```
file:///path/to/file/this.doc
```

Just like a hyperlink but without a domain name. Provided your shell knows how to open a file type then it will do so.

```
for i in $(ls); do echo "file://$(pwd)/$i"; done
```

`ctrl`+`click`

**EDIT**

To bring @tripleee excellent improvement out from the comments and into the answers...

```
printf "file://$(pwd)/%s\n" *
```

**END EDIT**

This will not work for files with spaces in the file names 
because the expansion of `$(ls)` produces a list of file names separated by spaces. A space **within** a file name will make the shell think it is actually two file names separated by a space.

```
my file.pdf
```

becomes

```
my
file.pdf
```

If you have spaces in your filenames then try this until you find a more elegant solution since I just hacked it in anticipation of the next question...... ;-)

```
for f in $(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname "*" | sed 's/ /%20/g'); do echo "file://$(pwd)/${f#*/}"; done
```

Just use `find` in the normal way to return the files you want.

Comment: I am confused, where does the search term go?

Comment: Can you update your question so that it helps someone in which you are not assuming knows bash-scripting as well as you? Thanks.

Comment: You can easily avoid the [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls); `printf "file://$(pwd)/%s\n" *`

Comment: @tripleee I count myself educated on this use of `ls` thats a nice little nugget of knowledge.